# How to start backgroundrb when Passenger starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a Rails application running under Apache+Passenger and using backgroundrb for some tasks. Is there any way to have backgroundrb start when Passenger starts? For example, after a server reboot I would like everything to start again without manual intervention to start backgroundrb or having to create an init script for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the call in an Rails initializer (`config/initializers`).

To do so only when a Passenger job is launched, wrap the call in something like...

```
if defined? PhusionPassenger
  PhusionPassenger.on_event :starting_worker_process do |forked|
    if forked
      ... spawn your backgroundrb here...
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this approach is that you'll end up spawning a new process with every Passenger worker process.  You'll need to put a check in to see if backgroundrb is already running.

Take a look at ShogunPanda's comment [here](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/10/) to see how we do it with Rufus Scheduler and PID files.  You should be able to do something similar.

Comment: the event name is ":starting_worker_process" and not ":start_worker_process"

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting this in your config/environment.rb file:

```
unless FileTest.exist?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/backgroundrb.pid")
    fork do
    exec("#{RAILS_ROOT}/script/backgroundrb", "run")
    end
end
```

Change /log/backgroundrb.pid to whatever pidfile your backgroundrb server uses and you should be off to the races...